# ElasticSearch - No result with stemmer

Tags: elasticsearch, porter-stemmer

I have a problem with stemming words.
When I use stemmer, words are not indexed, only digits are

I think my conf is bad, but I can't find solution on Internet, so I hope you can help me

Here is my conf :

```
PUT /myindex
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "french_stop": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords": "_french_"
                },
                "french_stemmer": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "language": "light_french"
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "stem": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "standard",
                        "lowercase",
                        "french_stop",
                        "french_stemmer",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
PUT /myindex/_mapping/mytype
{
    "properties": {
        "field": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "stem"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample word or set of words that to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I index "Vélos 123". No result for "Vélos", neither for "velo", but result for "123"

Comment: What query are you using?

Comment: I use Java REST client : Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("q", query);
params.put("size", String.valueOf(Constantes.SEARCH_RESULT_SIZE));
params.put("from", String.valueOf(page*Constantes.SEARCH_RESULT_SIZE));
params.put("analyzer", Constantes.ES_ANALYZER);

Response response = client.performRequest(
  "GET",
  String.format("/%s/%s/_search", Constantes.ES_INDEX, Constantes.ES_TYPE),
  params);

Comment: http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_search?q=velo&from=0&size=10&analyzer=stem

Comment: and what is the value of `Constantes.ES_ANALYZER` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to solve your problem:

A. You can specify the `stem` analyzer in your query by using

```
params.put("analyzer", "stem");
```

B. You can explicitly specify the field in your query string so that the proper analyzer is used at query time, i.e. your `query` variable needs to be prefixed with the field name:

```
query = "field:" + userQuery
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have already added "analyzer" param. And I can't specify a field because I want to search in all fields

Comment: What is the value of `Constantes.ES_ANALYZER` ?

Comment: Value is "stem"

Comment: Have you tried without specifying the analyzer at query time?

Comment: Works with exact matching, but not with stemmed word

Comment: weird as without specifying any analyzer I can find `Vélos` as well